# Address of structure itself

Tags: c, structure

How to find the address of structure itself?
 I heard something like the first variable of structure points the address of structure. I'm not clear about this. anyone can explain how to find this?

Comment: @ sahu, okay. thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
struct mystruct {
    int first;
    int second;
};

struct mystruct thing;
```

Then `&thing` and `&(thing.first)` are the same *(`&` is the "address of" operator)*.

As a complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct mystruct {
    int first;
    int second;
};

int main ( void ) {
    struct mystruct thing;

    printf("&thing is %p, &(thing.first) is %p\n",
        &thing, &(thing.first));
    return 0;
}
```

> **%** ./astest
>   &thing is 0x7fff57513910, &(thing.first) is 0x7fff57513910

Comment: thank you @john.  I understood it :)